# How can I upload an image in a canvas with FineUploader?

Tags: canvas, fine-uploader

On a web page, I have a canvas. I want to take what's in it and upload it to the server using FineUploader.

The FineUploader api has the addFiles method (http://docs.fineuploader.com/api/methods.html#addFiles) that is supposed to support canvas upload. But I can't figure out the options needed to make it work.

As I understand it, I need to create an instance of FineUploaderBasic.

```
var uploader = new qq.FineUploaderBasic({
    multiple: false,
    request: {
        endpoint: BASE_URL + '_ajax/endpoint.php'
    },
    autoUpload: false,
    debug: true
});
```

And then I call the addFiles method.

```
uploader.addFiles({
    canvas: document.getElementById('my_canvas'),
    name: 'canvas.jpg',
    quality: '60',
    type: 'image/jpg'
});
```

In the FineUploader debug I get the following message:

```
[Fine Uploader 5.7.1] Received 0 files.
```

I didn't find any helpful example by googling so can anyone tell me what are the expected options to make this work?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not seeing any obvious issues with this feature. Most likely you are passing a `null` value for `canvas`.

Answer (score 1):

I am also trying out FineUploader for uploading a canvas to a server. I have not tested the server yet, but I have found that using your code and passing the canvas object itself gives the desired response in the console (I am using fabric.js):

```
var canvas = new fabric.StaticCanvas('canvas');

var uploader = new qq.FineUploaderBasic({
    multiple: false,
    request: {
        endpoint: endpoint
    },
    autoUpload: false,
    debug: true
});

uploader.addFiles({
    canvas: canvas,
    name: 'canvas.jpg',
    quality: '60',
    type: 'image/jpg'
});
```

Console message:

```
[Fine Uploader 5.11.8] Received 1 files.
```

Comment: You can also pass a "bare" `<canvas>` as well - `uploader.addFiles(canvas)`.

Comment: Will give that a go as well later, thanks! Since my post yesterday I have tested the server and the canvas is being passed correctly.